# CLIPS will not assert a value from READLINE

Tags: string, symbols, assert, clips

I have a CLIPS routine that worked perfectly in version 5.1.  (It is a standalone that runs in CLIPSDOS or CLIPSIDE. There is no integration with other languages.)
 However, now that I am using 6.31 and 6.4 I find it will not function.  Notably, it will not accept a readline with an explode$ and let me assert it to the facts so the system can keep running.

Any suggestions?  I figure it has to be something very simple (or stupid) that I missed.

Quite honestly, I think I need to convert a single word 'string' to a symbol but haven't been able to find the conversion in the BPG for 6.31 or 6.4.

P.

Comment: You can use the sym-cat function to convert a string to a symbol. Otherwise, without knowing what you tried it's difficult to say why it didn't produce the results you want.

Comment: Thanks Gary, str-cat worked. Tried it last night.  Only problem I have now is I need to run each query twice to get all the results.